Adding a db to an AG - full backup required prerequisite, can I use that backup for the seeding?
I had to take a db out of the AG and put it in SIMPLE recovery model to do some high volume data copying.  Putting the db back into the AG using the wizard (after setting recovery back to FULL), it said a full backup is required (checkbox disabled).  I did a full compressed backup to a UNC share, then a log backup to the same share.  The checkbox was enabled on refresh, but I chose to do the full+log backups to a folder path again, increasing the task's duration (1 backup, 2 restores including a slow one to a different datacenter).  Could I have used my manual full+log to prep the secondaries?  I think it's the last option on the seeding screen.
Side note: I saw in sp_whoisactive during the full backup that it's a copy_only backup.  I normally disable our Rubrik backup service on the primary when doing AG work like this, since I don't want two processes competing for the backup chain.  Didn't realize the AG wizard uses copy_only.


Could I have used my manual full+log to prep the secondaries?

Yes, especially since they were already on a share. You can manually prep the database in an AG by restoring it and leaving it in a restoring state (NORECOVERY) on the secondary replica that needs it, then joining the database in either with the wizard (Join Only option) or by doing it manually using T-SQL (ALTER DATABASE ... SET HADR).
